# unconditional basis inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I'm reading a paper and having some trouble with a certain inequality.

Let $W$, $X$, and $Y$ be Banach spaces, with $(x_n)$ a normalized basic sequence in $X$ and $(w_n)$ a normalized *unconditional* basis in $W$.  Let $T:X\to Y$ be a bounded linear operator and let $\delta>0$.  Suppose there exist matching block basic sequences $u_n=\sum_{k\in I_n}a_kx_k$ and $v_n=\sum_{k\in I_n}a_kw_k$ such that $\|Tu_n\|<\delta_n\|v_n\|$ for all $n$, where we define $\delta_n=\delta 2^{-n}$.

**Claim of the paper:**  For any finite sequence of scalars $(b_n)$, we have $\|\sum b_n Tu_n\|<\delta\|\sum b_nv_n\|$.

What is the justification for this claim?

**Additionally,** I am curious about something else, which is not part of the paper I am reading.  Here is the object of my curiosity:  Suppose $(z_n)$ is a normalized basis for a Banach space $Z$ and that $S:Z\to Z'$ is a bounded linear operator between Banach spaces.  Let $C=\sup\{\|Sz_n\|:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.  What is a sufficient further assumption for $(z_n)$ to guarantee that $\|S\|=C$?  If $(z_n)$ need only be unconditional, then the above claim is immediate.  But that seems too good to be true, so probably more is required than just unconditionality.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Please give a reference to the paper: reading the original often helps one understand what is going on. As for the *additional* part, here is a *two-dimensional, Euclidean* counterexample: $S:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$  defined by $S(x_1,x_2)=x_1+x_2$. For the standard basis of $\mathbb R^2$,  we get $C=1$. But $\|S\|=\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot give a reference, nor can I expand too much on the context.  (It is not published, currently in preparation.)  The most I can say is that $(w_n)$ is perfectly homogenous (and hence equivalent to the unit vector basis of one of the classical sequence spaces $c_0$ or $\ell_p$, $1\leq p<\infty$), although this is not supposed to play a role in the above inequality.  Thank you for the counterexample though.  :)